# A surjective local homeomorphism between compact Hausdorff spaces is a covering map

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Is there a more brief/ intuitive way to show the following?

> Show that if $\;X, Y$ are compact Hausdorff spaces then a surjective local homeomorphism $\;f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a covering map.

[Note that we have nothing about connectedness here]

*Property 1*: a local homeomorphism is continuous and an open map

*Property 2*: if $A \subset X$, $X$ is Hausdorff, and $A$ is finite, then with each $x\in A$ we can associate a neighborhood $U_x$ such that $U_{x_1}$ doesn't intersect $U_{x_2}$ when $x_1 \neq x_2$

*Property 3*: a restriction of a homeomorphism is a homeomorphism.

*Property 4*: a continuous map between a compact space and a Hausdorff space is a closed map

*Property 5*: a compact Hausdorff space is normal

*Proof*:

Choose $y \in Y$. $\{y\}$ is closed (Hausdorffness of $Y$) so $f^{-1}(y)$ is closed (Property 1) and compact (Compactness of $X$).  For all $x \in f^{-1}(y)$ choose a neighborhood $U_x$ such that $f|_{U_x} : U_x \rightarrow f(U_x)$ is a homeomorphism.

Then for all $x, x' \in f^{-1}(y)$ such that $x \neq x'$, we have $x' \notin U_x$,  since $f|_{U_x}$ is injective.  Thus, $\{U_x\}$ covers $f^{-1}(y)$, but no subset of $\{U_x\}_{x \in f^{-1}(y)}$ is a subcover, so 
$$
0 < |\{U_x\}_{x \in f^{-1}(y)}|=|f^{-1}(y)| < \infty
$$
since $f^{-1}(y)$ is compact and $f$ is surjective.

Around each $x \in f^{-1}(y)$ associate a neighborhood $A_x \subset U_x$ such that $A_{x_1}$ and $A_{x_2}$ are disjoint when $x_1 \neq x_2$ (Property 2, Hausdorffness of $X$).  Each $A_x$ is homeomorphic with its image by $f$ under the restriction (Property 3).  Then let
$$
V = \cap_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} f(A_x)
$$
which is open since $f$ is an open map (Property 1) and $f^{-1}(y)$ is finite.

Next for each $A_x$, let $B_x \subset A_x$ be the preimage of $V$ under $f|_{A_x}$. Then each $B_x$ is disjoint and homeomorphic under $f|_{B_x}$ to its $V$ (Property 3).

Now, let $B^c = \left(\cap_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} B_x\right)^c$ which is closed.  Then $f(B^c)$ is closed (Property 4) and doesn't contain $y$ which is closed as a set.  Then since the space $Y$ is normal (Property 5, Compactness and Hausdorffnes of $Y$), we can choose a neighborhood of $y$, $V'$, that doesn't meet $f(B^c)$.

Finally, for each $B_x$, let $C_x$ be the open subset of $B_x$ which maps to $V \cap V'$.  Then

- each $C_x$ is open and homeomorphic to $V \cap V'$ under $f|_{C_x}$ (Property 3);
- the elements of $\{C_x\}_{x \in f^{-1}(y)}$ are disjoint; and
- if $z \notin \cup_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} C_x$ then either $z \in B^c$ so $f(z) \notin V \cap V'$ or $z \in B_{x_0}$ but $\notin C_{x_0}$ for some $x_0 \in f^{-1}(y)$ so $f(z) \notin V \cap V'$

Thus $V\cap V'$ is a neighborhood of $y$ such that $f^{-1}(V \cap V') = \sqcup_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} C_x$ and $f$ maps each $C_x$ homeomorphically to its image.

Comment: This is the proof I've always seen.

Comment: It seems to me you must require $f$ to be surjective.

Comment: @Federico If $Y$ is connected $f$ is automatically surjective as $f[X]$ is non-empty clopen, so equal to $Y$. But no connectedness here.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Oh yes, you're right!

Comment: @Federico ah yes thank you.  an omission in the theorem statement. have fixed it